# Subclassing SimpleAdapter and overwriting getView causing trouble with bindView()

Tags: android, subclass, simpleadapter

I just wanted to subclass SimpleAdapter and play around with color changing based on position (and other options making the elements more pretty and distinguishable from each other) but I'm having trouble overwriting the getView method. I just copied the code from the method which is called in the original getView method in the SimpleAdapter class, which is createViewFromResource and my code looks like this now:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)thecontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);

    } else {

        v = convertView;

    }

    bindView(position, v);

    return v;
}
```

There is nothing gamebreaking here, as I said it's 95% copy paste from the original adapters source, I just took some variables from my constructor instead of the private variables declared in the super class as I can't access these in the subclass. My problem is the bindView method that is called just before the view is returned. Eclipse isn't giving me any hint on what this is doing and I can't seem to call it from my subclass either.

> The method bindView(int, View) is undefined for the type ChangingColorAdapter

That's what I'm getting if I do use the code above, although I copied it from the original source. Seems a bit strange to me. I'm programming at API level 8 (2.2) and have the sources attached. If I take a look at the SimpleAdapters original source the editor can't tell me where the bindView call is going to, but it does not give any errors there.

Did I get anything wrong here or what's causing this problem? I can't seem to find any documentation or description on the bindView method, just example implementations, mostly from the cursor adapters. Any hints would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I totally messed up this one. After sleeping for some hours I just found the bindView() method in the SimpleAdapter class. It doesn't have any java-doc and I could swear that I couldn't ctrl-click the function yesterday, but today it just works fine. As the method is private you need to reimplement it which I did and it now runs just perfectly smooth.